# Cannot Debug IOS app made in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

this is my first time developing a mobile app using Xamarin.Forms.
I've been trying for some days to solve this problem, but i can't figure it out.

Basically, i'm trying to debug the app on my IPhone, it builds successfully and it gets installed on the phone but when i run the app (as required from the debugger), it just displays the splash screen and then it crashes (after 5+ seconds).
Checking the debug console, i find this error:

```
2021-09-17 22:14:04.323 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[1911:423723] Xamarin.iOS: Successfully received USB connection from the IDE on port 10000, fd: 6

2021-09-17 22:14:04.331 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[1911:423723] Xamarin.iOS: Processing: 'start profiler: no'

2021-09-17 22:14:04.332 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[1911:423719] Xamarin.iOS: Profiler not loaded (disabled)

Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5ED8EF08-A25E-4025-AF71-83D55AEA145F/mvfit.iOS.app/Xamarin.iOS.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5ED8EF08-A25E-4025-AF71-83D55AEA145F/mvfit.iOS.app/System.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5ED8EF08-A25E-4025-AF71-83D55AEA145F/mvfit.iOS.app/Mono.Security.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5ED8EF08-A25E-4025-AF71-83D55AEA145F/mvfit.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS.exe [External]
Thread started:  #2
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5ED8EF08-A25E-4025-AF71-83D55AEA145F/mvfit.iOS.app/Xamarin.iOS.HotRestart.Application.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5ED8EF08-A25E-4025-AF71-83D55AEA145F/mvfit.iOS.app/netstandard.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5ED8EF08-A25E-4025-AF71-83D55AEA145F/mvfit.iOS.app/System.Core.dll [External]
2021-09-17 22:14:05.060 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[1911:423719] Content folder: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9F20DC06-5BAB-43F1-BD66-D480944CAAEE/Documents/mvfit.iOS.content

Thread started:  #3
2021-09-17 22:14:05.075 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[1911:423719] Forms app path /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9F20DC06-5BAB-43F1-BD66-D480944CAAEE/Documents/mvfit.iOS.content/mvfit.iOS.exe

Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9F20DC06-5BAB-43F1-BD66-D480944CAAEE/Documents/mvfit.iOS.content/mvfit.iOS.exe
2021-09-17 22:14:05.077 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[1911:423719] Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS' (culture: '')
2021-09-17 22:14:05.077 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[1911:423719] Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS' (culture: '')

2021-09-17 22:14:05.081 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[1911:423719] Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'mvfit' (culture: '')
2021-09-17 22:14:05.081 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[1911:423719] Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'mvfit' (culture: '')

Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9F20DC06-5BAB-43F1-BD66-D480944CAAEE/Documents/mvfit.iOS.content/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9F20DC06-5BAB-43F1-BD66-D480944CAAEE/Documents/mvfit.iOS.content/mvfit.dll
2021-09-17 22:14:05.115 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[1911:423719] Xamarin.Forms AppDelegate name: AppDelegate


=================================================================
    Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================
Got a segv while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

=================================================================
    Native stacktrace:
=================================================================

    0x1042e009c - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5ED8EF08-A25E-4025-AF71-83D55AEA145F/mvfit.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_dump_native_crash_info
    0x1042d6bdc - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5ED8EF08-A25E-4025-AF71-83D55AEA145F/mvfit.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_handle_native_crash

    0x1042e39b8 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5ED8EF08-A25E-4025-AF71-83D55AEA145F/mvfit.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_sigsegv_signal_handler_debug
    0x1e6bf429c - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib : <redacted>
    0x1afa77660 - /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib : <redacted>
    0x19ab773b4 - /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : <redacted>
    0x19ab67948 - /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : <redacted>
    0x19ab77f30 - /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : <redacted>
    0x19ab779c0 - /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : <redacted>
    0x19ab79928 - /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : <redacted>
    0x19ab6aecc - /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : <redacted>
    0x10448a4d4 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5ED8EF08-A25E-4025-AF71-83D55AEA145F/mvfit.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : do_icall
    0x104488b94 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5ED8EF08-A25E-4025-AF71-83D55AEA145F/mvfit.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : do_icall_wrapper
    0x10447fa88 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5ED8EF08-A25E-4025-AF71-83D55AEA145F/mvf
it.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : interp_exec_method_full
    0x10447e018 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5ED8EF08-A25E-4025-AF71-83D55AEA145F/mvfit.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : interp_runtime_invoke
    0x1042e6c70 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5ED8EF08-A25E-4025-AF71-83D55AEA145F/mvfit.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_jit_runtime_invoke
    0x1043937a8 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5ED8EF08-A25E-4025-AF71-83D55AEA145F/mvfit.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_runtime_invoke_checked
    0x104398b54 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5ED8EF08-A25E-4025-AF71-83D55AEA145F/mvfit.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_runtime_exec_main_checked

    0x1042cb7d8 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5ED8EF08-A25E-4025-AF71-83D55AEA145F/mvfit.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_jit_exec
    0x10447c0f8 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5ED8EF08-A25E-4025-AF71-83D55AEA145F/mvfit.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : xamarin_main

    0x104292944 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5ED8EF08-A25E-4025-AF71-83D55AEA145F/mvfit.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : main
    0x19ab65cf8 - /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : <redacted>

=================================================================
    Basic Fault Address Reporting
=================================================================
Memory around native instruction pointer (0x10d85fe88):0x10d85fe78  f6 57 c3 a8 c0 03 5f d6 00 08 40 f9 c0 03 5f d6  .W...._...@..._.
0x10d85fe88  f4 4f be a9 fd 7b 01 a9 fd 43 00 91 1f 20 03 d5  .O...
{...C... ..
0x10d85fe98  08 0d 02 58 00 01 40 fd 1f 20 03 d5 21 fb 00 5c  ..
.X..@.. ..!..\
0x10d85fea8  00 20 61 1e 65 02 00 54 e0 e7 01 30 1f 20 03 d5  . a.e..T...0. ..

=================================================================
    Managed Stacktrace:
=================================================================
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at ObjCRuntime.Dlfcn:_dlopen <0x00026>
      at ObjCRuntime.Dlfcn:dlopen <0x00010>
      at ObjCRuntime.Dlfcn:dlopen <0x00010>
      at <>c:<Main>b__0_0 <0x0000c>
      at System.Action`1:invoke_void_T <0x0007c>
      at Xamarin.iOS.HotRestart.Application:LoadFrameworks <0x00072>
      at Xamarin.iOS.HotRestart.Application:Run <0x0018e>
      at Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS.Applications:Main <0x0005a>
      at <Module>:runtime_invoke_direct_void_string[] <0x00092>
=================================================================

Thread started: <Thread Pool> #4
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #5
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #6
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #7
L'app è stata terminata.
```

I'm working on Visual Studio 16.11.3, Windows 10, and i have an active paid Apple Developer Account.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [question](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vs-167-xamarin-android-crash-on-start-up-in-debug/1139203.) in vscommunity, it seems like version related issuse, so you may need to upgrade your visual studio and try again.

Answer (score 0):

When I removed Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material in the ios project, it worked.

Comment: from where did you remove this assembly.  I can't find in my ios project

Comment: Then you don't have it in your project

Answer (score 0):

When your App starts and crashes in few seconds, the problem could have been on the Initializing of components. One of the assembly required for initializing components could not be resolved and your app crashed.

From your debug console: "...... Unable to locate assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS' ....."

Go to references of the iOS project, open the property of specific assembly and check if the assembly was able to be resolved. If not remove and reinstall using nuget for the iOS project only (not Android or Solution level). Ensure no assembly has unresolved status.

In the next Run, you should get your App's landing page.[Resolve assembly reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JRNX.png)